# How to reset or unset a view height or width which were set programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I am struggling with this and I cannot find a direct answer to this question due to its generic keywords leading the results to unrelated questions.

If I set a view's height or width programmatically, for example:

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.myButtonId)).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
```

How can I unset/reset/revert this process so the view's height (or width) returns to its default behavior before that size was set?

I am trying to find something like the `Html CSS` equivalent of `height: unset` or `height: initial` or even the JavaScript way for inline styles `some_dom_element.removeAttribute("style")`

Is there anything to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just save the initial height and then set it back to that number when you are done?

Comment: @nhouser9 The views have dynamic sizes (`match_parent`, `wrap_content`, etc.) Unless I can detect which one is it in order to save that initial property, then I cannot restore it afterwards. Do you happen to know if this is possible and how to do it? If you do then I would appreciate if you could post as an answer for me to test and approve if successful.

Comment: Can't you just dynamically get the height using the same code you already posted? `int oldHeight = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.myButtonId)).getLayoutParams().height;`?

Comment: It can't be done that way because the heights will be different if the height is restored in a different orientation than the one it had when the height was first saved. For example, in portrait mode I save the view initial height and make my changes, I change to landscape orientation and then change the height to the initial height, which larger in portrait and won't work correctly in landscape. Do you understand the problem? This is why it needs to detect which type of height it had initially for your suggestion to work so the orientation (or anything else) does not affect the initial height

Comment: @nhouser9 I finally confirmed that your suggestion was correct, I've posted my answer for now to help others, but if you could I would like if you could post yours as an answer so that I can accept yours.

Comment: props to you for researching this more and figuring it out. I upvoted your answer and posted my own if you want to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem you should save the height before modifying it. Then when you want to reset it, you can revert to the original height. Luckily, the special cases of `MATCH_PARENT` and `WRAP_CONTENT` are represented as integer constants, so this works even for those cases (credit to OP for researching this point).

So, the solution is something like this:

```
int initial_height = view.getLayoutParams().height;
```

And then when you want to set the height back to its previous value, just reference the `initial_height` to do so correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to nhouser9 idea and the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT I have managed to work a solution for this problem. The basic idea is the same, save the initial value so it can be restored after, however first you need to find out whether the view height or width has a fixed or dynamic value and which dynamic value it is, so for my case I have used the following process

```
int initial_height;
switch (view.getLayoutParams().height) {
    case LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT:
        initial_height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        break;
    case LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT:
        initial_height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        break;
    default:
        initial_height = view.getLayoutParams().height;
}
```

But I then understood that the dynamic sizes (`match_parent`, `wrap_content`) do have specific values, respectively -1 and -2, according to the documentation, meaning that nhouser9 suggestion worked directly since these dynamic sizes could be acquired directly from the view's dimensions (-1, -2 or positive if fixed size). This means that all that it takes now is to just save the initial size directly, like so

```
int initial_height = view.getLayoutParams().height;
```

And that's it. This answer was left here to help anyone looking for the same solution and I will be waiting for the other user to post his answer so that I can choose his as it was his help that got me to the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reset height to Wrap Content :

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams llp = date.getLayoutParams();
                    llp.height= ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                    date.setLayoutParams(llp);
```