# Reset button height to layout standard wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with button children. On rotation of the device I need to change the height of all the buttons to fit the screen under some conditions. My problem is that after orientation changed to horizontal all widgets height needs to match their text content.

Thing's that I've tried:

```java
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I also tried to

```java
button.forceLayout();
```

Button layout:

```xml
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/AppButtonMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:showIn="@layout/fragment_kanban_menu" />
```

@style/AppButtonMenu:

```xml
<style name="AppButtonMenu">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|left</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/margin_base_2x</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">@dimen/margin_base_05x</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">@dimen/margin_base_3x</item>
</style>
```

I'd like not to use the solution of this [How to reset or unset a view height or width which were set programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045976/how-to-reset-or-unset-a-view-height-or-width-which-were-set-programmatically)

Comment: We need to see your item row layout of `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I managed to get the behaviour that i needed by setting the adapter:

mAdapter = new WidgetsAdapter(WidgetList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: I'd like to find a more light way to do this anyway...